# rewrite, using the distributive property $0.04 (12x + 8)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a couple of problems like this and need to know the basics of getting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$0.04(12x+8)=(0.04 \cdot 12x)+(0.04 \cdot 8)=0.48x+0.32$$

Equivalently, and more general:

$$A(B+C)=(AB)+(AC)$$